# Literature on teaching and learning probability

Tags: education-research, reference-books, probability

In an earlier [question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/5730), the book *Exploring Probability in School* (2005) ([Link](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387245294)) was mentioned. It gives an overview of the research on the teaching and learning of probability up to that point.

Does there exist a similar book on the same topic with a more recent publication date covering the newest research in the field? If not, what are the important new papers to read on that subject?